# How do you make two functions work side by side in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new to python and am taking a course at my school, I was given the homework of making a clock that counts down from 1 or 2 hours and also shows the minutes seconds and hours the whole time. I started to do the code and defined 2 functions, seconds, and minutes. Seconds counts down from 60 seconds and minutes does the same thing except from 1 minute, I tried them seperatly and they worked, then I tried them together and I couldn't get them to work side by side. How can I make them do this, also, should I just be using a variable that counts down? Any help is appreciated.

```python
from time import *
def seconds():
    while 1==1:
        time_s = 60
        while time_s != 0:
            print (time_s)
            sleep(1)
            time_s=time_s-1

            os.system( [ 'clear', 'cls' ][ os.name == 'nt' ] )

def minutes():
    while 1==1:
        time_m = 60
        while time_m!= 0:
            print (time_m)
            sleep(60)
            time_m = time_m-1`
```

Also, indents might be messed up.

Comment: Yes they do, I am only allowed to use a certain amount of moduals like time threading, etc. I am Not allowed to use my computer's internal clock because it is too "easy" but thanks for the tip, I will remember for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

As there are sixty seconds in a minute. You don't need to calculate them separately. Just calculate the total amount of seconds and divide by 60 to show the minutes, and modulo 60 to show the seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Your Desired Complete Program

```
    import threading
    import logging
    import time

    time_m=60
    time_s=60
    time_h=24

    print ('Karthick\'s death Clock Begins')

    def seconds():
       while 1==1:
          global time_s,time_m,time_h
          time_s = 60
          while time_s != 0:
              print (time_h,':',time_m,':',time_s)
              time.sleep(1)
              time_s=time_s-1

              os.system( [ 'clear', 'cls' ][ os.name == 'nt' ] )

    def minutes():
        while 1==1:
            global time_m
            time_m = 60
            while time_m!= 0:
                time.sleep(60)
                time_m = time_m-1

    def hours():
        while 1==1:
            global time_h
            time_h = 24
            while time_h!= 0:
                time.sleep(360)
                time_h = time_h-1

m=threading.Thread(name='minutes',target=minutes)
s=threading.Thread(name='seconds',target=seconds)
h=threading.Thread(name='hours',target=hours)

m.start()
s.start()
h.start()
```

Enjoy Programming :-)!